# Pipe Dope (or Tape) on a Propane Cooktop

Tags: leak, pipe, propane

I have a Koblenz propane cooktop in my cabin and it recently developed a gas leak. Here's a video of my soap test https://youtu.be/uhKAhUsWaUY.

The manufacturer says I should use pipe dope (or tape) to fill up the treads and stop the leak but I've heard conflicting advice about the safety of this.

The pipe coming out of the back of the cooktop goes into a brass fitting and finally the hose from my propane tank screws into that. I'd be putting the pipe dope between the stove's pipe and the brass fitting.

It can get hot in this area when the burner closest to it is used for extended periods of time so whatever I use needs to be heat resistant and propane friendly.

[image: Leak location]

Comment: First try tightening this joint a little; this may stop the leak. If it does not, unscrew that joint and see what kind of joint it is. Pipe thread joint compound ("dope") is only to be used for pipe threads (that are exposed to the gas). This joint may be a different type. It may have a soft seal that the threads serve only to hold together. If that is the case, pipe dope will not help. But id it is a pipe thread joint, there are plenty of pipe joint compounds that are inert to propane. You could first try the yellow Teflon tape.

Comment: @JimStewart thanks so much for your response. I tightened it as far as I felt safe tightening it. There is no soft seal so I'll try some yellow tape. Ultimately I think I might toss/recycle this stovetop. I would never forgive myself if I burned down my cabin and the surrounding forest.

Comment: A tiny leak will not start a fire. If you massively over tightened it, then it could fracture. Presumably there is a cutoff valve on the propane tank. If you have the white teflon tape you could use several turns of that or pipe dope (paste). The yellow color in the teflon tape is just there to indicate that this is a thicker tape so even one layer would be sufficient for a gas pipe connection.

Comment: What have you  heard that makes you wonder about the safety of pipe dope? There is no problem with pipe dope. It is an essential sealant for pipe threads.

Comment: How about letting us know how this was resolved?

Comment: @JimStewart I had heard pipe tape or compound was not to be used on tapered compression fittings. My situation is not one of those so I'm probably ok. I'll be taking a roll of yellow teflon tape with me when I go back to the cabin. I will report back after my next trip (unless I burn everything everything down to the ground) :)

Comment: Take a tube of pipe dope with you too.

Comment: Pipe threads are tapered so that as the threads are turned the fit of the threads gets progressively tighter.  The threads on compression fittings are not tapered. The purpose of the threads is to hold two sealing faces together. The faces are sometimes conical (male-female) but are not called tapered.